# SQL Many-To-Many relationships

Tags: mysql, sql-server

**Question**

Is there a way to have a many-to-many relationship among 3 tables without the use of automatic incrementers (usually ID), or are ID's required for this?

**Why I ask**

I have 3 relative tables.  Since one-to-one relationships seem to can't happen directly, I made a 4th to do one-to-many relationships to the other 3 tables.  However, since there's still a primary key to each table, a value can only be used once in a table, which I don't want to happen.

**What I have**

- Connectors has multiple Pockets which have multiple pins.
- The 4th Table is ConnectorFullInfo
  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes you could do it this way. Of course you need to make sure no duplicate primary keys are inserted into your database. Note: pocket info.connectorname is an unnecessary foreign key association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement that a table have an "automatic incrementer" as a primary key.

But, a familiar pattern is to add a surrogate ID column as primary key on entity tables. The "ideal" primary key will be "anonymous" (carry no meaningful information), "unique" (no duplicate values), "simple" (single column, short simple native datatype), ...

There are a couple of schools of thought on whether it's a good idea to introduce a surrogate key. I will also note that there are those who have been later burned by the decision to use a natural key rather than a surrogate key. And there are those that haven't yet been burned by that decision.

---

In the case of "association" tables (tables introduced to resolve many-to-many relationships), the combination of the foreign keys can be used as the primary key. I often do this.

BUT, if the association table is itself turns out to be entity table, with it's own attributes, I will introduce a surrogate ID column. As an example, the association between `person` and `club`, a person can be a member of multiple clubs, and a club can have multiple members...

```
club +--< membership >--+ person
```

When we start adding attributes to `membership` (such as `status`, `date_joined`, `office_held`, etc... at that point `membership` isn't just an association table; it's turning into an entity. When I suspect that an association is actually an entity, so I'll add the surrogate ID column.

The other case where I will add a surrogate ID column to an association table is when we want to allow "duplicates", where we want to allow multiple associations. In that case, I will also introduce a surrogate ID column.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that explanation. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: "BUT, if the association table is itself turns out to be entity table, with its own attributes, I will introduce a surrogate ID column."  In that case, do you make the new surrogate ID column the new clustered PK and replace the old composite PK with a nonclustered unique index?  I'm currently faced with that exact situation so I'm curious.

Comment: @MarredCheese: I've done it both ways,1) changing the cluster key to be the ID column, and 2) leaving the cluster key as is and just adding a new unique index on the (non-NULL) ID column. (With InnoDB, we don't actually have to define a PRIMARY KEY, we could just make two UNIQUE INDEX (on non-NULL columns) and InnoDB will choose one of the indexes to be the cluster key. By declaring one of the indexes as the PRIMARY KEY, we are telling InnoDB which should be the cluster key.. Consider: the cluster key will be included in secondary index, will secondary index be a covering index, ...

Comment: @MarredCheese: when there isn't a performance penalty (considering how execution plans for existing SQL will be affected) ,  I will make the new surrogate ID column the PRIMARY KEY, and define the composite key (which was the PRIMARY KEY) as a UNIQUE INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but,

It is customary to represent a table row by a unique identifier which is the number, its becomes more efficient.